# How to order by absolute value of column in sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase

I want to sort records based on absolute value of a column in sybase. Can someone please let me know how to do it? I tried below query but it throws error.

```
SELECT *  FROM table_name ORDER BY ABS(COL_A)
```

**Update** : table name was missing in query. added it.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You have to select the absolute value before you can sort by it.  Also, your query does not have a table name.

Comment: The only thing you are really missing is the TABLE name you are selecting from.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY ABS(COL_A)
```

Comment: How could `COL_A` not be in the `select` list with `select *`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your right, it shouldn't. I thought it might be a weird Sybase thing, but its not.  Maybe he's just missing the table name.  From Sybase's documentation "If a query has an order by or group by clause that includes columns not in the select list, Adaptive Server adds those columns as hidden columns in the columns being processed. The columns listed in the order by or group by clause are included in the test for distinct rows. To comply with ANSI standards, include the order by or group by column in the select list."

Comment: The column on which i am performing order by is of varchar type. But it actually holds only numeric values. Will it still work ? I guess this is the problem.

Comment: @chidori Whats the error you get?  Also you can try `ORDER BY CAST( COL_A AS NUMERIC)`